# need multiple variables in a string

Tags: php, string, variables

Unsure how to get this string to work correctly. Keeps making my page blank.

```
$imagefile = "http://mysite.ca/uploads/pages/large/$flyer['flyer_id']/$page['large_image']";
$imagedata = getimagesize($imagefile);
$imagewidth = $imagedata[0];
$imageheight = $imagedata[1];
```

I think it has something to do with both variables mixed in with regular text.

Comment: an example output would be
http://mysite.ca/uploads/pages/large/83/best-buy-flyer-mar-23-to-291.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not embed the variables in your string:

```
$imagefile = "http://mysite.ca/uploads/pages/large/".$flyer['flyer_id']."/".$page['large_image'];
```

or wrap them in `{}`:

```
$imagefile = "http://mysite.ca/uploads/pages/large/{$flyer['flyer_id']}/{$page['large_image']}";
```

or remove the quotes around the array key (it is perfectly allowed inside a double-quoted string):

```
$imagefile = "http://mysite.ca/uploads/pages/large/$flyer[flyer_id]/$page[large_image]";
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But when I try to echo $imageheight or $imagewidth nothing is printed. When I echo $imagefile I get the correct full path to the image.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` to see all errors. Maybe `url_fopen_wrappers` are disabled on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the mustache brackets (sorry can't remember what they're actually called) around your variables to allow them to be read properly as variables.

```
$imagefile = "http://mysite.ca/uploads/pages/large/{$flyer['flyer_id']}/{$page['large_image']}";
```